# Entity framework: String was not recognized as a valid Boolean

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

When loading data with Entity Framework I get this exception:

> String was not recognized as a valid Boolean.

I use Code First Entity framework with MySql database.

**I found out the problem is with my bool columns. When I alter them directly in MySql to use type BIT instead of automatically generated TINYINT, everything works.** But is there a way to solve it without manually changing the data type in database?

I tried adding this in my DbContext:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Properties()
                .Where(x => x.PropertyType == typeof(bool))
                .Configure(x => x.HasColumnType("bit"));
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

But this seems to affect only new migrations in which I'm adding a bool column. Then they are of correct db type BIT.

But the initial model had some bool columns too. And when I drop all tables and call Update-Database to recreate it, it generates them with TINYINT type, which again produces the error when loading the data. And again I have to fix it manually in database.

Comment: Have you tried creating a new migration after you changed the onModelCreating function ?

Comment: @BrentBoden Yes, it produces empty migration.

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to alter the old TINYINT column to be BIT? Or you want to use them in your program regardless of what type they are between the two?

Comment: @KristófTóth Any of these two that will prevent my program failing with the exception. But if had to choose, I'd pick former.

Comment: But how can you add a new column? You have one tinyint and one bool column now? There should have been a migration when you ALTER the TINYINT column to be of type bit

Comment: I created class `Entity` with one bool property `A`. I called `Update-Database`. Now I have in my database TINYINT A. I added new bool column `B` and called `Add-Migration Test` and `Update-Database`. Now I have TINYINT A and BIT B in my db. And finally when I change A column to type BIT manually in DB and try to add migration it produces empty one as if nothing has changed.

Comment: Changing data type to bit helped.